# ProcessingでのP3Dを用いたウェブカメラによるキャプチャーができない

Tags: processing

GitHubにある [tado/CreativeCodingExamples](https://github.com/tado/CreativeCodingExamples/tree/d06cbfd7338a4fb81d5844b9620bf5577d3898d9/list11_15) のコードを実行したのですが、黒い画面が表示されるだけでした。
また、ターミナルには以下のエラーが表示されました。

```
X11Util.Display: Shutdown (JVM shutdown: true, open (no close attempt): 2/2, reusable (open, marked uncloseable): 0, pending (open in creation order): 2)
X11Util: Open X11 Display Connections: 2
X11Util: Open[0]: NamedX11Display[:0, 0x7f9b84007040, refCount 1, unCloseable false]
X11Util: Open[1]: NamedX11Display[:0, 0x7f9b8401c450, refCount 1, unCloseable false]
```

しかしコード上のP3Dを削除し、vertexの引数をi,jのみにすると線だけは表示されるようなりました。
またP3Dに設定し、ウェブカメラの入力をそのまま表示させるプログラムの場合は問題なく表示されました。
どうすればエラーなく実行させられるでしょうか。

**実行環境**
OS: Windows 10, Fedora 33 (Workstation)
Processing: 3.5.4
Ryzen CPU, Nvidia GPUを使用

ウェブカメラはUSB接続のものを利用しています。どちらのOSで実行しても動作致しませんでした。

以下はウェブカメラの入力を表示させる（映す）コードです。
質問の条件の通り、P3Dを指定しています。

```java
import processing.video.*;
Capture cam;

void setup() {
  size(800, 600, P3D);
  frameRate(60);
  cam = new Capture(this, width, height);
  cam.start();
}

void draw() {
  image(cam, 0, 0);
}

void captureEvent(Capture c) {
  cam.read();
}
```

また実行後に表示されるウィンドウを閉じた後に出力されるログですが、上記の赤字のログ以外に以下のものが白文字で出力されました。

```
Processing video library using GStreamer 1.18.2
```

Comment: ウェブカメラの入力をそのまま表示させるプログラムでは size が 800, 600 になっており、今回動かないプログラムでは 800, 500 になっていますね。動かない方のプログラムで 800, 600 にしたらどうなりますでしょうか？

Comment: sizeを800,600を設定しましたが、変わらずbackground(0)の色のままでした。

Comment: むむむ、カメラから取得できる解像度の制限にひっかかっている訳でも無さそうですね。以下を教えて欲しいです: (1) Processing 標準のエディタをお使いでしょうか？　(2) ログには他に何も出力されていないでしょうか？（表示されていたら質問文に追記していただけるとありがたいです）　／　"X11Util.Display: Shutdown" で検索したら類似の事例がいくつかヒットするところまでは見ているのですが、 https://github.com/processing/processing/issues/6090 や https://stackoverflow.com/q/17938261/5989200 に代表されるように、ピッタリ来る解決法を見つけられていません。なので原因の切り分けをしたいと思っています。

Comment: （1）はい、Processing標準のエディタを使用しております。（2）リンク、ありがとうございます。出力されるログについては追記致します。お手数をおかけ致します。